# typeof object of array of object in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

How do I replace `any` below with `options's` object shape below?

```
interface selectComponentProps {
  options: {
    label: string;
    value: string;
  }[];
}

const SelectComponent: React.FC<selectComponentProps> = ({
   options,
}) => {
  const handleChange = (selectedOption: any) => { //here
    
  };

  return (
    <Select
      options={options}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: `(selectedOption: typeof options[0])` should work

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the model for a single option to a separate interface:

```
interface selectComponentProps {
  options: selectComponentPropsOption[];
}

interface selectComponentPropsOption {
  label: string;
  value: string;
}
```

Then you can replace `any` with `selectComponentPropsOption`.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1.

```
const handleChange = (selectedOption: typeof options[0]) => { //here
    
};
```

Option 2.

```
interface Option {
  label: string;
  value: string;
}
interface selectComponentProps {
  options: Option[];
}
const handleChange = (selectedOption: Option) => { //here
    
};
```